# C# javascript datagrid column count?

Tags: javascript

How many data can I count in the datagrid?

```
var a = $('#grdHisse').getDataGrid().count;  - wrong
var a = $('#grdHisse').rows.count; -wrong
```

I use to specific datagrid (Specific framework).

```
@(Html.OdakGISHelpersNew().UI.DataGrid
.SetAjaxUrl("/Data/DataPaging/")
.SetId('grdHisse')
.SetRowSelectionMode(DataGridRowSelectionMode.MultipleRows)
.AddColumn("Name", "Name")
.Render())
```

Comment: Where's your HTML code? Also, try using `.length`.

Comment: Can you add more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to select table rows with jquery and use length.

```
var count = $('table tr').length;
```

Comment: `length` has no parenthesis.